# Robotium Tests not running on Jenkins but local

Tags: jenkins, robotium

i try to integrate my Robotium Tests on our Jenkins Server. I implemented an android Test Project that based on our app Project. Everything works like a charm when i run the Tests on my local Machine on Windows out of Eclipse and also by calling from shell by call

```
'adb shell am instrument -w <our-package>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
```

So far, so good, but after i set up a build Job in Jenkins, let the Projects build by maven clean install sign etc. none of my tests will be proceeded. I also tried to call `'adb shell am instrument -w <our-package>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'` as shell command after the build step but also no result. The build ended up with just 2 Tests shown log below

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3571502822112946903.sh
+ /home/jenkins/tools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell pm list instrumentation
instrumentation:com.android.emulator.connectivity.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=com.android.emulator.connectivity.test)
instrumentation:com.android.emulator.gps.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=com.android.emulator.gps.test)
instrumentation:com.zeppelin.zemos.test.addispo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=com.zeppelin.zemos.addispo)
+ /home/jenkins/tools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell am instrument -w com.zeppelin.zemos.test.addispo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

android.test.AndroidTestCase:.
android.test.LoaderTestCase:.
Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=..
Time: 0.031

OK (2 tests)
```

Just the 2 Tests AndroidTestCase and LoaderTestCase are shown up and it seems that all of my other Testcases (i've implemented 11) are not processed by Jenkins.

I spent a long time googling around but found no solution for this. Could this be a ant Problem? I have Version 1.8 local and 1.6 on the Jenkins Server. Or is there another Problem i cannot see.....

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is Jenkins rechecking out your project? it could be that is still building and running an old version.

Comment: commit all your codes, checkout them to a temp folder in your own computer, try them again see if has the difference of jenkins do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uninstalling the package from device/ emulator, using
"adb uninstall your_package"
Then, do a clean debug install again and then run the tests.